# Database Design Circular Reference

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to modify a C# .NET MVC web app and existing database to implement some new functionality. However, try as i might, i cannot modify the database structure without creating a circular reference and i was hoping someone may have a solution.

I want to implement a method of order routing. So depending on thresholds set on a customer an order will be produced one of two ways depending on the order size. So i find when i design the database the customer needs to reference the routing table as it dictates when an order comes where it should go. Also because an order is attached to a route it also needs to reference the routing table which results in a circular reference:

[image]

The customers, products and order are already in production so i would be nervous about modifying those relationships if required.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not related to C# if you are not using entity framework, and what you are trying to do is allowed in SQL. SQL does not work on OOPS package design principles. And referencing a table is as good as creating linkage between tables without applying any OOPS principle. What is the issue here?

Comment: Apologies if this is the wrong place. I should have said that I am using Entity Framework as my ORM and want to try and get the design as good as possible before i dive into modifying code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, you don't have a circular reference!
If I understand the problem, you want to configure each customer with one of two routes (above and below threshold). Then, the order will go as per that route (order route)

First, the meaning of the foiregn key in the above three relationship is different, one determining preference, and one determining actual

Then, the actual route that the order took is the one attached to it. If you don't have a requirement of tracking history (like, how does this order took this route while the customer is constraint to one of different two?) then I see your design - for this particular question - is valid

I still don't know why the PRODUCT table is linked to customer the way it is! Maybe it is then a CUSTOMER_PRODUCT, but that's outside your question

You can get the route certain order needs to take by selecting:

```
 select case when :thresh > threshold then aboveThresholdRoute else belowThresholdRoute end
 from customer 
 where id = :customer_id
```

Where threshold is calculated based on whatever formula you have, and for the order customer

Comment: Thank you for the help BA. Having re read your answer today it makes a lot of sense. For now im going to keep the structure similar to my original post and see how things go.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the schema that is `already in production` does not seem extensible enough. However, your customer does NOT need to be referencing `Route`. A `Route` is a property of an `Order`, and an `Order` is a property of the Customer (via `Product` association).

So you need to create a new `Routes` table, like so

```
CREATE TABLE Routes
(Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
Name NVARCHAR(50));
```

Then alter Order table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE Order ADD RouteId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
ALTER TABLE Order ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Routes_Id FOREIGN KEY (RouteId) REFERENCES Routes(Id);
```

Then, to select the Routes for the user:

```
SELECT * FROM Routes 
INNER JOIN Order 
ON 
    Routes.Id = Order.RouteId
INNER JOIN Product
ON
    Product.LastOrder = Order.Id -- Assuming that is the FK here, not clear from the question
INNER JOIN Customers
ON 
    Product.CustomerId = Customers.Id
WHERE 
    Customers.Id = 'some value here'
```

**UPDATE**
Since you now mentioned routes are user specific, rather than order specific, you can simply change it like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Routes
(Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
Name NVARCHAR(50));
```

Then alter Customers table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD RouteId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Routes_Id FOREIGN KEY (RouteId) REFERENCES Routes(Id);
```

Then to select route for an order, do:

```
 SELECT * FROM Routes 
    INNER JOIN Customers 
    ON 
        Routes.Id = Customers.RouteId
    INNER JOIN Product
    ON
        Product.CustomerId = Customers.Id
    INNER JOIN Order
    ON 
        Product.LastOrder = Order.Id -- Assuming that is the FK here, not clear from the question
    WHERE 
        Order.Id = 'some value here'
```

Comment: Hi Zaitsman and thank you for the detailed reply, it is very much appreciated. I think my issue is that with this implementation, i am not sure how a new order will be assigned the correct route as this routing is customer specific. perhaps this is more of a programming related sub question than a database design question.

Comment: @Boggot Well, then we just need to change the entity to which to attach the route, see update. Arguably the whole schema needs changing.

Comment: thanks again for your help. you have mentioned a couple of times that the schema needs changing in your eyes. If you had the ability to modify it, what would you do if you dont mind me asking. Thanks again